# Why is "wrapper" is better name for a decorator than "adder"?

Tags: python, wrapper

A bare-bones example of a decorator is:

```
def strong(func):
    def wrapper():
        return '<strong>' + func() + '</strong>'
    return wrapper
@strong
def greet():
    return 'Hello!'
```

`wrapper` is an entitled name for the 'inside first-order-function' inside the Higher-Order function `strong`.

My question is that the word `wrapper` has no real meaning except to confuse newbie. Why not use 'adder', because it can be discerned intuitively?

> [Decorator pattern - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)
>   In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behavior to be **added** to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class.[1]

The keyword in Wikipedia's explanation is 'added'.

And in [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/decorate):

> to **add** something to an object or place, especially in order to make it more attractive:

The keyword is also 'add'.

So why is `wrapper` better than 'adder'?

Comment: The *behavior* is added. The *code* is wrapped.

Comment: Because the function *wraps* the string in `<strong>` tags, which IMO is more descriptive in terms of what it does, though it's still up to personal opinion.

Comment: "Adder" already has a well-established meaning in the computer field. "Wrapper" is not confusing at all: the decorated function is being wrapped in another function. The term is blessed by the Python designers as well: see `functools.wraps()` and the `__wrapped__` attribute.

Comment: In this case, it's both: typically decorators wrap other functions (i.e. allow additional code to be run both before the function and after it); and in this case, as Li357 says, the tags also literally wrap the string returned by `greet`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is crossposted to softwareengineering, where there is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a decorator, you've wrapped your original code in another function, making the original function invisible.  To continue your example,

```
def strong(func):
    def wrapper():
        return '<strong>' + func() + '</strong>'
    return wrapper
@strong
def greet():
    return 'Hello!'

def weak_greet():
    return 'hi'

print(greet)
print(weak_greet)
```

If you run this, you get the following output.

```
<function strong.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000000000129A268>
<function weak_great at 0x000000000129A2F0>
```

When you used the decorator, you took your function, created a new function that wrapped code around your old function and returned that new, anonymous, function.

You can see some unpleasant effects if you try to pickle it.

if you do `pickle.dumps(weak_greet)`, you get `b'\x80\x03c__main__\nweak_great\nq\x00.'`. but if you try to `pickle.dumps(greet)`, you get `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'strong.<locals>.wrapper'`. (dealing with decorated classes and functions that must be pickled is one of the circles of hell I don't wish to revisit any time soon).

You are not adding to your function. You are wrapping your original function in a shiny new function.  That new function says, "There's something I'm hiding in here and I won't tell you what it is (functools.wraps can sometimes help with this, as it would in your case). But, when you give me input, I'll alter it like so (or not at all), pass it to my secret function, (possibly) alter the output and give you that. Your original function is inaccessible (hence pickle's confusion).

**NOTE:** You can re-create the look of your original function by further wrapping your wrapper with `@functools.wraps(original_function)`, which does not affect output, but wraps everything in a box to make it look exactly like the original function.  so,

```
from functools import wraps
def strong(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper():
        return '<strong>' + func() + '</strong>'
    return wrapper
```

would now look like your original function and be pickle-able. It would be like wrapping a surprise present, and then wrapping the present again with wrapping paper that told you (in great detail) what the surprise was.